# C# include (type behaviour)

Tags: c#, include

I have a set of applications that will pass a particular structure between each other.
I would like to have just one definition of this structure, and have each of the applications reference it.
In C / C++ I would do this by having an #include reference to the .h file containing the definition of the structure.  I understand that this isn't possible in C#, but I would like to know the best way to acheive a similar thing.

I am using Visual Studio 2012, each application is its own project.  I have one Solution which contains the various projects.  If I try to drag and drop the TagData.cs file (which contains the structure definition) into any projects then the file itself is copied into the Project directory (which is not what I want, since this results in multiple copies of the definition).

I'm sure this is a simple question, and there must be an easy solution, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'd want to do here is move those pieces that are shared into a third project and reference that new project from the other two.

If this is not possible (different platforms between projects where the types you're using wouldn't be supported by a PCL profile), you can right click on the project you're looking to include the file in, select `Add Existing Item...` browse to the file in question, and, instead of just clicking `Add`, select the down arrow just to the right of it and click the `Add as Link` option.

Comment: The 'Add as Link' was exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.